# update query in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have below `update` query in hibernate i want to update column of `BudgetAllocatedToFormations` table when i execute query

```
this.session.createQuery("UPDATE BudgetAllocatedToFormations batf,BudgetAssignedSubHeadOfAccounts bashoa,BudgetSubHeadOfAccounts bshoa "
    + " SET batf.balanceBudget = "+balanceBudget+""
    + " WHERE batf.budgetAssignedSubHeadOfAccounts.budgetAssignedSubHeadOfAccountId = bashoa.budgetAssignedSubHeadOfAccountId"
    + " AND bashoa.budgetSubHeadOfAccounts.budgetSubHeadOfAccountId = bshoa.budgetSubHeadOfAccountId"
    + " AND bshoa.budgetSubHeadOfAccountId = "+subHeadOfAccountId+""
    + " AND bashoa.budgetFormations.budgetFormationId = "+formationId+""
    + " AND batf.budgetFinancialYear.budgetFinancialYearId = "+financialYearId+""
    + " AND batf.isApproved = 1 AND batf.isLocked = 1 AND batf.isActive = 1").executeUpdate();
```

i get
**error:**

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] line 1:94: expecting "set", found ','
ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] line 1:94: expecting "set", found ',' 
line 1:94: expecting "set", found ','
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.setClause(HqlBaseParser.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:140)
```

i am using hibernate 4.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Your double quotes are not placed correctly. You should use parameters (named or positional) instead of concatenation.

Comment: i am not updating multiple table, i update only one table but matching `id` from multiple tables can you guide me how can i do that ?

Comment: is this sql or mysql?

Comment: this is `mysql` query

Comment: you have problems with your double quotes, you should use parameters anyways

Comment: i cant understand your answer

Comment: I am referring the two double quotes you have at end of line 2. But you need to use parameters instead of string concatenation. See here for a quick tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/